# Get Full Content of XML Item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have an XML file that has items that look like this:

```
<CutOffItem>
    <partnum>SAIT22021</partnum>
    <diameter>4-1/2"</diameter>
    <width>0.045"</width>
    <arbor>7/8"</arbor><material>METAL</material>
    <maxrpm>13300</maxrpm>
    <brand>UNITED ABRASIVES, INC.</brand>    
    <imgsrc>style\images\Original Bolt Pics\Abrasives\Cutoff\SAIT 4.5-8in.jpg</imgsrc>
</CutOffItem>
```

I am referencing each element via jQuery to use in an HTML document like this:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$partnum = $xml.find( "partnum" );
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
$category = $xml.find( "category" );
$type = $xml.find( "type" );
$diameter = $xml.find( "diameter" );
$width = $xml.find( "width" );
$arbor = $xml.find( "arbor" );
$brand = $xml.find( "brand" );
$imgsrc = $xml.find( "imgsrc" );
```

And displaying them like this:

```
//Title
var h3 = document.createElement('p');
h3.innerHTML = $title.text();
$('#item').append(h3);
```

All is working as intended, but when I try to do this to the img src:

```
// IMG
var img = document.createElement('img');
var src = document.createAttribute('src');
src.value = $imgsrc.text();
img.setAttributeNode(src);
$('#item').append(img);
```

The img element that displays on the HTML page code looks like this:

```
<img src="styleimagesOriginal Bolt PicsAbrasivesCutoffSAIT 4.5-8in.jpg">
```

**.text() removed all forward slashes from the URL. How can I keep the forward slashes?**

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery. For image, try removing your code for this, and implement the following:

```
// IMG
$("#item).append("<img src="+ $imgsrc + "title="+ $brand +"></img>");
```

For the long term, spacing in the url of the image is generally not the best. It should be URL encoded %20 for each space. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

However that is your call.. Good luck!!